# Link that goes directly to the Android Market in a Webview

Tags: android, android-webview, google-play, webviewclient

In my Android, if I click on on a link that leads to the Play Store, Android automatically opens up the play store so that I can download the app.

If that link is in a webview for the app, instead a webpage opens, similar to the one that would open on a desktop. Is there any way around this? The type of links that I have tried are:

market://details?id=com.alpinereplay.android (doesn't work at all in a webview)
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appname.android (opens up a desktop like website)

Comment: That's disappointing -- I would have expected `market://` to work. Push come to shove, you could implement your own scheme (e.g., `davidmarket://`) pointing to a `Theme.NoDisplay` activity of yours that turns around and starts up the regular `market://` activity.

Comment: Yea, that's what we would do, except that the app is already IN the market, so I can't change any of the native code.

Answer (score 3):

I'm actually quite surprised that this behavior is happening. Are you sure it's not something you're doing explicitly? The docs for [`shouldOverrideUrlLoading`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29) in a `WebViewClient` say:

> by default WebView will ask Activity Manager to choose the proper handler for the url.

If you have a `WebViewClient` make sure you have code in `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` to decide when to launch the Play Store vs. load the page in the `WebView`--perhaps by [parsing the URL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29), [getting the scheme](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#getScheme%28%29), and using the `market` scheme for your URLs.

Answer (score 0):

By default, if you do not set any `WebViewClient`

```
webView.loadUrl("market://details?id=your_package");
```

method doesn't work, it shows page not found.
If you try to load a page that contains a market link and if you do not set `WebViewClient`, this page will be opened in device browser, so you should set a `WebViewClient` and because you set a `WebViewClient`; you should handle market links yourself like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13886357/1503078) suggested.

But the following link inside your custom html opens market app even if you do not set a `WebViewClient`. I think this is the situation mentioned in documentation of [`shouldOverrideUrlLoading`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29).

```
String html = "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"//www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\"><html><head> </head> <body>  <p><a href=\"market://details?id=your_package\">Market Link</a></p>  </body></html>";
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", html, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```